# FreeCell stack moving

Tags: code-golf, card-games

This question is about moving stacks around in the card game [FreeCell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeCell), but here it will be presented more abstractly.

Given three integers \$0\le n,m<10000,0<k<10000\$.

There are \$m+2\$ columns, \$m\$ of them empty and two of them contain cards (from bottom to top) \$[0,-2,k]\$ and \$[0,-3,k-1,k-2,\cdots,1,0]\$. Besides, \$n\$ empty cells exist.

In each move, you can move the top \$i\$ cards of a column/cell to the top of another preserving order, if:

- After the move, each cell contain at most one card;
- If there are \$a\$ empty columns (not counting destination) and \$b\$ empty cells, then \$i\le (a+1)(b+1)\$. (See revision for more detailed background)
- After the move, all these moved cards are either at the bottom or on a card that is one larger than itself. (For not-bottom moved cards, that mean they are each "on a card that is one larger than itself")

Output the number of moves required to make the two columns contain \$[0,-2,k,k-1,k-2,\cdots,1,0]\$ and \$[0,-3]\$. Output something unambiguous (not a positive integer) and constant (same for every impossible mission) if it's impossible.

Samples:

```
1 1 4 -> 1
2 0 4 -> Impossible
0 2 4 -> 3 (see *)
0 2 3 -> 1 (direct moving allowed)
16 16 88 -> 1
```

*:

```
[0,-2,4][0,-3,3,2,1,0][][]
[0,-2,4][0,-3,3,2][1,0][]
[0,-2,4,3,2][0,-3][1,0][]
[0,-2,4,3,2,1,0][0,-3][][]
```

Shortest code in each language win.

## Notes

- For those who know FreeCell, suits doesn't matter in this problem, and the 4/6/12 limit also doesn't exist.
- The "0,-2,k" and "0,-3" mean you are not supposed to move k or -3 away, as there's no way to put them back.

Comment: As I recall, FreeCell on Windows only allows you to move either 1 card or the maximum possible to an empty pile.  This behavior affects inputs like `0 3 8`.  What is the intended output in this case?

Comment: @Nitrodon The one on xp only allow 1 or max, but Win7 allows any amount by dragging

Comment: @JonathanAllan Anyway a total rewriting isdone

Comment: That is now much clearer to me what we are to do! I've voted to reopen. (Might be worth noting that the examples' inputs as given are \$n, m, k\$)